# How to prevent Kendo UI Grid from rebinding many times when updating ViewModels

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

When you bind to a Kendo UI Grid with MVVM, databound will fire once and all is well.  If you need to update that data after the fact, every time you change one piece of data on any viewmodel (or child viewmodel), the entire grid re-databinds.  Thus, if you had some cell in the grid that is bound to a template and you have to change 2 or 3 properties on the viewmodel from some external ajax source, Databound will fire 2 or 3 times for each model that is changed, causing the entire viewable area to rebind.  How can we update lots of data at once and only have databound fire once?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How exactly you rebind the Grid? Basically if you change some of the models like this:

```js
dataItem.set('SomeField','new value');
dataItem.set('someOtherField','other value');
```

This way the Grid will be indeed bound two times because of the MVVM. The change event is triggered each time you call set.

However if you update the values like this:

```js
dataItem.SomeField='new value';
dataItem.someOtherField= 'other value';
```

The Grid wont react to the change and wont rebind re-read the values from the models you can force the Grid to do it through the **refresh** method.

```js
$('#gridName').data().kendoGrid.refresh()
```

Comment: This approach works fine as long as you know what element(s) you are bound to.  If the data you are updating is bound to more than one thing and it is being updated in some sort of library where you don't care about the screen elements, this could cause some issues.  If you call set() on the very last item's property, then you won't care what is bound to it.  They'll all get the update.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is some way to temporarily tell the grid to stop listening to events and then at the end, re-sync once.  If there is, please give that answer here!  Otherwise, what I did instead is I didn't go through .set() for each item.  Instead, I updated the data for all the rows by setting the data directly to the property.  Then when I got to the very last row I was updating, I called .set() on the last property that needed to be updated.  This will cause databound to fire only once and the entire grid will refresh itself with all the data that was changed.  If you don't do it this way, then the more rows displayed on the page, the longer it takes to process. (It could take 20+ seconds before the user can do anything again.)

Comment: Another way is to simply add some bogus property to the last item and change its value at the end.  It'll cause the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the dataBinding event is where you can prevent a rebind on the grid.

[Telerik Online Docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-dataBinding)