# Kendo Grid Acting Weird on Update

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid which is acting weirdly. I'm trying to select a row and update value in the data source. The grid has 2 rows: one template i.e. check box and one value in data source which is Boolean.

All I'm trying to do is:

> When clicked on checkbox - Update the value of `IsChecked` in the data
>   source and mark the row as selected

**The code below works fine but only after each check box is clicked at least once**.

*To replicate:* Click on any checkbox, you'll see the value in the row gets updated, but check box is not checked. Click on it again and you'll see the check box gets checked and row gets selected. But never on first time. Same happens with all the rows. After 2nd run they work fine, but not at first.

Here is the [Telerik fiddle link](http://dojo.telerik.com/UNIpU/2) to play around

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    {
         title: "Check",
         template: '<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" />'
    },

     { field: "IsChecked" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    {  IsChecked:false},
     {  IsChecked:false },
     {  IsChecked:false },
     {  IsChecked:false }
  ],
   dataBound: function () {
                    $(".checkbox").bind("change", function (e) {

                        var row =  $(e.target).closest("tr");
                        row.toggleClass("k-state-selected");

                        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                        var index = $("tr", grid.tbody).index(row);

                        var data = grid.dataSource.at(index);
                        data.set("IsChecked", true);


                    });
                }
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. Working fiddle http://dojo.telerik.com/UNIpU/3

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [{
            title: "Check",
            template: '<input class="checkbox"  #= IsChecked ? \'checked="checked"\' : "" #  type="checkbox" />'
        },

        {
            field: "IsChecked"
        }
    ],
    dataSource: [{
        IsChecked: false
    }, {
        IsChecked: false
    }, {
        IsChecked: false
    }, {
        IsChecked: false
    }],
    dataBound: function(e) {
        var grid = e.sender;
        var data = grid._data;

        data.forEach(function(entry) {
            if (entry.IsChecked) {
                $('tr[data-uid="' + entry.uid + '"]').addClass("k-state-selected");
            } else {
                $('tr[data-uid="' + entry.uid + '"]').removeClass("k-state-selected");
            }
        })
    }

});

$("#grid .k-grid-content").on("change", "input.checkbox", function(e) {
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid"),
        dataItem = grid.dataItem($(e.target).closest("tr"));

    dataItem.set("IsChecked", this.checked);
});
```

Comment: I see. Thanks Ankush :)

Comment: Hey but do you know what is causing the grid to behave erratically with my code?

Comment: every time you call set method grid rebind itself and again databound is called. And you were calling set method in databound.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15579857/how-to-prevent-kendo-ui-grid-from-rebinding-many-times-when-updating-viewmodels